# Solr can't find single word when using LowerCaseFilterFactory

Tags: solr

I have a small set of documents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="HelloWorld" version="1.5">
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">Erstes Dokument</field>
        <field name="content">Das ist der Inhalt des ersten Dokuments</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">Zweites Dokument</field>
        <field name="content">Und hier der Inhalt von Dokument zwei.</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">Drittes Dokument</field>
        <field name="content">Häufig enthalten Dokumente ein Mélange verschiedener Sprachen</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

and the following schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="HelloWorld" version="1.5">

<types>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">

        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/> 
</types>

<fields>
    <field name="id" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true" omitNorms="false"/>
    <field name="content" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
</fields>

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>content</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

</schema>
```

When I comment out the LowerCaseFilterFactory I can find the term Dokument in the field content in the second document. With the LowerCaseFilterFactory in place I can't find it anymore. Interesting is, that I can find it in combination with another word in the second document, for example when I search "zwei Dokument".

In the analysis of the Solr-Admin the index seems to work correctly:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: `Interesting is, that I can find it in combination with another word in the second document, for example when I search "zwei Dokument"` ==> This is due to the fact that you are using OR query so Solr will find `zwei`. I suppose that you allready did that but have you reboot Solr and reindex your data?

Comment: Are you searching with `"`?

Comment: Yes, I restarted Solr after changing the index. And no, I don't use quotes. The strange thing for me is, that with LowerCaseFilterFactory, Solr only finds Dokument in combination with another word (i.e. zwei). Without LowerCaseFilterFactory it finds the word Dokument or Dokument in combination with another word.

Comment: Did you try with Solr admin to see what happens? (Did you reindex your data?)

Comment: As far as I know Solr reindexes when the server is restarted. That's what I did. I added a screenshot of the Solr-admin's analysis to this post. For my opinion, it looks like the index is working correctly. But the query still returns nothing for Dokument.

Comment: So according to the admin, the terms match. Reindex manually !

Comment: `As far as I know Solr reindexes when the server is restarted` --> this is not true ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this one is solved. What I did now was deleting the core, creating the core new and reload the data. Even just deleting the indexes folder did not work. But now it works as expected.

Comment: No, I tried that before deleting the core. Thanks for your help.